# Xslt: how to sum previous elements

Tags: xslt

I have an issue to  sum specific elements ,
I want to sum all the previous element by specific value 
for this xml i want to get something like that,

I want to sum all the LinkedQuantity elements previous to  **LinkedQuantity = -14**

```
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(//*[local-name()='LinkedQuantity'][preceding::*][text() != -14])"/>
```

But its sum up the values after -14 as well .

```
<product>
<TransactionLink ReasonCode="Subtract">
    <LinkedSequenceNumber>10</LinkedSequenceNumber>
    <LinkedQuantity>-2.000000</LinkedQuantity>
</TransactionLink>
<TransactionLink ReasonCode="Subtract">
    <LinkedSequenceNumber>10</LinkedSequenceNumber>
    <LinkedQuantity>-4.000000</LinkedQuantity>
</TransactionLink>
<TransactionLink ReasonCode="Subtract">
    <LinkedSequenceNumber>10</LinkedSequenceNumber>
    **<LinkedQuantity>-14.000000</LinkedQuantity>**
</TransactionLink>
<TransactionLink ReasonCode="Subtract">
    <LinkedSequenceNumber>10</LinkedSequenceNumber>
    <LinkedQuantity>-12.000000</LinkedQuantity>
</TransactionLink>
<TransactionLink ReasonCode="Subtract">
    <LinkedSequenceNumber>10</LinkedSequenceNumber>
    <LinkedQuantity>-7.000000</LinkedQuantity>
</TransactionLink>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to sum all the LinkedQuantity elements previous to **LinkedQuantity = -14**

Taken literally, that would translate to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(//LinkedQuantity[.=-14]/preceding::LinkedQuantity)"/>
```

However, with the given example, it would be more efficient to write:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(/product/TransactionLink[LinkedQuantity=-14]/preceding-sibling::TransactionLink/LinkedQuantity)"/>
```